# Include Uncompiled Library in Qt Application

Tags: qt, build, portability, qmake, autotools

I am writing a markdown editor in Qt. I have an OS X laptop, a Windows laptop, and a Linux desktop and I would like for the application to work on all three. This means **custom dependencies must be compiled at build time**, and I don't know how to do this.

I am using the [Discount markdown engine](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/%7Eorc/Code/discount/) to process the markdown to HTML and [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) for syntax highlighting in `<code>` blocks. Obviously the JavaScript will not be a problem but Discount might be. Discount will compile in all three of my target operating systems, but **I don't know how to include the library without compiling it**.

#### The Include Internal Library Window Looks Like this

[image]

But the "Library" field will not accept anything other than a compiled library or a project directory based on QMake .pro files. Because Discount uses GNU Autotools and not QMake, this poses a difficulty for me - especially because **I am not very familiar with either M4 syntax or QMake syntax.** What should I do?

Comment: If you don't change the library a lot, better to compile the library first instead of include it as sources.

Comment: @Apin I realize that would probably be the easiest option but that would mean I would have to create separate Qt projects for each platform, and at that point why am I even using Qt?

Comment: If you are using the QMake, you can create the .pri file that consist all source file of your library and then include those .pri file on your .pro file

Comment: @Apin hmmm ok I've never heard of a .pri file. I'll look into this.

Comment: Or in your .pro file you can specify per platform what library to include.